# Matomo's Live API not respecting date

Tags: matomo

When I use Matomo's *Live API* for getting the user's profile with *getVisitorProfile()*, the passed in date is ignored.

```
curl  -N  -i -X POST -d 'token_auth=xxxlanguage=en&format=json&module=API&method=Live.getVisitorProfile&idSite=1&date=yesterday&period=day&segment=eventCategory==MediaVideo&visitorId=xxx' https://myurl.matomo.cloud/index.php
```

Triggering this command I get all last visits and not the requested time period. Is it a bug or meant to be? If it is intentionally, what would be the right query or method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Live.getVisitorProfile` in the Matomo Reporting API does not have an option for date, the only options it accepts are `idSite, visitorId = '', segment = '', limitVisits = ''`

You can see what options are available for the Live API in the Reporting API Reference docs here: https://developer.matomo.org/api-reference/reporting-api#Live